Typing a branch/leaf structure in TypeScript
In TypeScript I have:
type Leaf = string[];
type Branch = { [id: string]: Branch | Leaf };

let someBranch:Branch;
let leafOrBranch:Branch|Leaf = someBranch.someSubBranch.someSubSubBranch.someLeafOrBranch;

This gives me the following error (which makes sense):
Property 'someSubSubBranch' does not exist on type 'Branch | Leaf'.
  Property 'someSubSubBranch' does not exist on type 'Leaf'.ts(2339)

I could do
let someLeafOrBranch:Branch|Leaf = ((someBranch.someSubBranch as Branch).someSubSubBranch as Branch).someLeafOrBranch;

...but that becomes annoying pretty fast.
Is there a way to change the types so that I can just call someBranch.someSubBranch.someSubSubBranch.someLeafOrBranch without giving any errors?

you mean the error says instead "Property 'someSubSubBranch' does not exist on type 'Leaf'"?

@GiorgiMoniava correct.. changed it (the actual names in my code would make the example less clear so so I altered them to Branch and Leaf but made a typo)

You can do this to get the desired type, it does not require type assertion, but only works with properties that are explicitly given inside the generic type.

This feels like the opposite of what TS is for. You might as well just write (someBranch as any) and do any indexing you want. Giving Branch completely unconstrained keys while Leaf has all kinds of array props also makes this very difficult, since branch.foo.bar.length is what? If you can add structure to Branch then you can get closer to what you want this way with optional chaining, but it's still crazy. I'm not sure what the intent is here; could you [edit] to explain whether you care about type safety and if not, why any isn't good enough?

@jcalz any means that type Leaf | Branch can not only be a branch or array of string but also any other type like number or string.
However I wasn't sure if something like this would be possible to begin with in TypeScript but judging from the answers it's probably not..
The suggested answers don't appeal to me either so I guess I'll stick to the solution that I already used ( (someBranch.someSubBranch as Branch).someLeafOrBranch )
Everyone thanks for the answers and thinking along!

It should be giving error if you want type safety, so if you just want to avoid it you can just config to ignore it.
If you do want type safety you should have some checks, you can use something like:
function isBranch(value: unknown): value is Branch {
    return typeof value === 'object' && value !== null && !Array.isArray(value) && Object.keys(value).length > 0;
}

if (isBranch(someBranch.someSubBranch) && isBranch(someBranch.someSubBranch.someSubSubBranch)) {
    let leafOrBranch: Branch | Leaf = someBranch.someSubBranch.someSubSubBranch.someLeafOrBranch;
}

It is still annoying, but it's better than using as since it just ignore type check.

If you're certain that the initial branch has the structure that you expect, you can type it that way and the compiler will emit no corresponding diagnostic:
TS Playground
declare const someBranch: {
  someSubBranch: {
    someSubSubBranch: {
      someLeafOrBranch: Branch | Leaf;
    };
  };
};

const leafOrBranch = someBranch.someSubBranch.someSubSubBranch.someLeafOrBranch;
//    ^? const leafOrBranch: Branch | Leaf


However, if you're not certain about the initial branch structure, then using a series of type assertions will only suppress helpful compiler diagnostics about syntax that would potentially cause a runtime exception.
Alternatively, you can use a function to iteratively index into your branch by providing an array of property accessors which correspond to the nested branch/leaf, and validate the structure along the way, like this:
TS Playground
function getNested(
  branch: Branch,
  propertyAccessors: readonly (keyof Branch)[],
): Branch | Leaf {
  let result = branch as Branch | Leaf;
  for (const prop of propertyAccessors) {
    if (!Array.isArray(result)) {
      const child = result[prop];
      if (typeof child === "object") {
        result = child;
        continue;
      }
    }
    throw new Error(`Invalid porperty accessor: "${prop}"`);
  }
  return result;
}

declare const someBranch: Branch;
const leafOrBranch = getNested(someBranch, [
  "someSubBranch",
  "someSubSubBranch",
  "someLeafOrBranch",
]);


